# Hibernate: version check based on group identifier version

Tags: hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

I have a service where data can be updated for a specific group identifier.
That group identifier is stored as a field/column in the entity like this:

```
class MyEntity {
   private String groupIdentifier;
   // other fields
}
```

The users may send the following request:

```
{   
    "groupIdentifier":"group1" 
    "createOrUpdate": [
        { "action": "CREATE", otherfields},
        { "action": "UPDATE", "id":123, otherfields}
    ]
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve:
2 users load the same data, first user updates the data successfully and second user tries to update the same data again: I want to detect that second call was for a stale data.

I don't want to use any kind of pessimistic locking or mutually exclusive flags as this is a rare case, but I'd like to provide a clear message to the user, that his data is not up-to-date and needs to be updated before doing further updates.

Is making groupIdentifier a separate Entity with @Version attribute the best solution here? Will hibernate update the version each time there is new entity which references it or each time there is a change to existing entity for that group?

Answer (score 1):

The operation is correct like this. At the end they will update an entity by ID and the data from the last update will prevail.

Thing that from a functional point of view I do not consider a problem, suppose that two users want to update a wrong entry, there are two options, or that they update both with the same data so there would be no problem, or that they are different so in code cannot determine which is the correct entry.

If you want to set a "semaphore" you will have to implement a flag manually, for example when a user opens the edit form update a field of the DB input to 1 and when it exits it returns it to 0 and in turn a check when opening the edit form that the edit flag is at 0.

Another option would be to add audit fields to the input (date and user) and check before updating that the initial audit date (when opening the form, for example) is equal to the current audit date (just before updating ), this would indicate if there has been a modification while editing the form.

Comment: "Semaphore" would be hard to manage, you need to clear the flag after timeout. Also you don't know if user is reading information to change it later or not. Let me provide more info in the question.

Comment: Also,  "last update will prevail" is not the case here, as creation of the entity binds it to another "not bound" entities(of another type), so one can't simply create/update something, there is a logic which should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Another option would be at the moment that user 2 loads the original entity (which remains out of date) using BeanUtils.copyProperties to make a copy of it, and that you can modify the parameters without losing the original entity. At the time of saving the new one, throw a query by id to the DB (to be as fast as possible) and compare with BeanComparatorsif there have been modifications in the entity, in positive case you show the notice to User 2.

Comment: While this can be possible in some cases, the users I am talking about is a UI application sending requests to a backend. Updating the contract to start sending initial version + new version doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Moreover, as you can see in updated question there are some dependent entities + not only updates but creates as well.